# Getting Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here: ( In Flutter While Setting up Admob)

Tags: android, flutter, admob

I Am trying to add Admob in my flutter application, i have done everything what i saw on youtube videos and documentation of admob still i am getting an error.

```
enter code here : E/AndroidRuntime(10500): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get 
                   provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: 
                   java.lang.IllegalStateException:
                  E/AndroidRuntime(10500):
                 E/AndroidRuntime(10500): 
          ******************************************************************************
      E/AndroidRuntime(10500): * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
    E/AndroidRuntime(10500): * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
    E/AndroidRuntime(10500): * to find your app ID.
```